# Installing Printers on Windows Embedded Standard 7 OS

Tags: printers, windows-embedded-standard

we are Developing an application on  Windows Embedded Standard 7 OS and We are using .net C#.

One of the feature in our application, printing a report and we need to select a printer. On the device we don't have a CD Drive and Client don't want to expose the explorer to user.

Finally we decided and At factory, we can install some standard printers which are commonly used. But if the user have a different printer or user decided to change the printer after some time and user don't want to call ther service engineer. In these situations, how to install the printers.

On Device, we have USB ports and may be useful.

Are there are any ways to handle this problem.

if you have any link I should go thru or any document I need go thru. Please share.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If the printer is USB and recognized by Windows, simply plugging it in will install the print driver and create the printer.  Otherwise, you're going to have to provide the printer driver yourself somehow and utilize either the Win32 `AddPrinterDriver` and `AddPrinter` functions, or use the [Rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee624057.aspx) method, which will require all the print driver files and its .inf file.

Comment: Thank you Carey. Let me try this.

Comment: @341184 - The two approaches I suggested are non-trivial and not easily implemented.  I would have provided more detail but it's not clear to me exactly what you're trying to accomplish.  If you edit your question to add more detail, I might be able to provide a better answer.